# Scikitlearn latent dirichlet allocation is giving empty topic

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using the sklearn implementation of LDA for topic modelling.
After the fit of the model, I get some topics meaningful with words having gains weights so that's fine, however I also get other topics with all the words' weights egals to the prior (1 / number of topics). This behaviour sounds strange to me, what could it be the cause ?

Information about my setting are :

- Vocab of 1000 words
- I am passing to the model a ffidf matrix done using this vocab over 700+ documents, each document is between 500 and 1000 characters
- I have tried to run different number of em iterations, that does not change the result
- I am asking for 30 topics

I also wonder if it might come that I have too many topics, but if it's indeed the case, should not the model change the weights of the topics anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302965/some-topics-with-all-equal-weights-when-using-latentdirichletallocation-from-sci/303858#303858) but in my case, it was related to having only a few number of (large) documents. In such a scenario, the Online Variational Bayes method, which is implemented in scikit-learn, has problems finding informative topics (Gibbs sampling based methods work, however).

I think in your case, the problem is that you're passing a "ffidf matrix" (I think you mean *tfidf* matrix). As far as I know, LDA only works with discrete numbers, hence you need to pass the *tf* matrix (term frequency aka bag of words aka document term matrix – *DTM*).